# SQL - Select distinct only one column

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I select from a few columns, but only select `DISTINCT` results from one of these columns? This is what I have now:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(ur.user_by), urs.username
    FROM 
          ( SELECT *
            FROM users 
            LIMIT 10
         ) AS ur
      LEFT JOIN 
          people AS urs 
        ON 
          ur.user_by = urs.username 

    LIMIT 10
```

Although, the `DISTINCT(user_by)` doesn't work.

Comment: Try use group by. I think is good idea

Comment: Where should that be added? Do you mind posting an example? Pretty new to SQL.

Comment: Please add some sample data and the desired output you are looking for

Comment: @MahmoudGamal I simply want to select the data as above (if I remove the DISTINCT()) it works. However, I only want to select the values in "ur.user_by" once. Since there can be the same value multiple times.

Comment: @oliverbj and which `expire` and `username` values are you expecting ? You'll have to group by and aggregate them in order to output only one row per `user_by`.

Comment: @oliverbj - OK, but what if there are multiple duplicated values for the other columns, which value should you select among these values for each group of `user_by`? You have to use `group by` and sort of aggregate function, thats why we need to see sample data in order to understand what you are trying to select exactly.

Comment: In the "people" database urs.username there is only ONE value for each user. Therefore, I want to select the users from "users", but only once (since there can be multiple values for each users). Forget about the "expire" for a minute. I'll update my question.

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function on a column, it's a part of SELECT DISTINCT and works on the whole selected rows. SELECT DISTINCT(ur.user_by), urs.username can be written as SELECT DISTINCT ur.user_by, urs.username, and can also be written as SELECT DISTINCT ur.user_by, (urs.username)... I.e. the ( )'s make no difference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP BY urs.username` with `MAX(urs.username)` will give you distinct values for username:

```
SELECT ur.user_by, MAX(urs.username) AS username
FROM 
      ( SELECT *
        FROM users 
        LIMIT 10
     ) AS ur
  LEFT JOIN 
      people AS urs 
    ON 
      ur.user_by = urs.username 
 GROUP BY  ur.user_by
 LIMIT 10;
```

In order to get distinct values, you have to use `GROUP BY` with an aggregate function to select only one row for each group. In your case `MAX` will work find with `username` and only select one value for each group of `user_by`.

---

**Update:**

To select only 10 unique users from the users table, you use `DISTINCT user_by` with `LIMIT 10` inside the subquery itself, like this:

```
SELECT ur.user_by, MAX(urs.username) AS username
FROM 
(
        SELECT DISTINCT user_by
        FROM users 
        LIMIT 10
 ) AS ur
  LEFT JOIN 
      people AS urs 
    ON 
      ur.user_by = urs.username 
 GROUP BY  ur.user_by
 LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: If there is example 20 "duplicate" values for the ur.user_by, it will only select ONE user. If I set limit to 30 for example, it will then select the next unique value. How can I select 10 unique users?

Comment: @oliverbj I still think, as Mahmoud Gamal suggested you 17 minutes ago, that providing a sample data and expected output would have made the question a lot clearer...

Comment: @Mahmhaiud Gamal I just want to select unique values from "users". If I have a limit on 10, I want 10 different, unique values, not 1 value (because the same values appear more than 10 times)

Comment: @oliverbj - See my updated query, you just need to add `DISTINCT user_by` to the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use GROUP BY

```
SELECT ur.expire, ur.user_by, urs.username
    FROM 
          ( SELECT *
            FROM users 
            LIMIT 10
         ) AS ur
      LEFT JOIN 
          people AS urs 
        ON 
          ur.user_by = urs.username 
    GROUP BY ur.user_by, urs.username,ur.expire
    LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Care to explain ? I (honestly) don't see the difference between `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` when there is no aggregation (using `select DISTINCT...` instead of the OP's invalid syntax of course)

Comment: This answer doesn't work, all he did is add the distinct to the whole clause which is pretty much the only behavior we know OP doesn't want.

Comment: @JulienBlanchard In fact, I don't know what the OP's looking for.

Comment: @X.L.Ant I am looking to select the data as in my question, BUT to select unique/distinct results for ur.user_by

Comment: Something that will be done through `group by`, not sure what though. The one thing  Iunderstand is that he doesn't want a simple `select distinct`

Answer (score -1):

I believe DISTINCT(column) needs to be first in your list of selects?

Comment: Why the vote down? I get syntax errors in MySQL 5.6.22 if I don't put DISTINCT(column) as the first SELECT field.

Comment: and does your query work? Because it doesn't for me, it still uses all the columns to evaluate the "distinct".

Comment: It may not be the entire answer, but it still corrects an aspect of the OP's issue. The OP has even since edited their post to include my advice, so I still don't feel it justifies a down vote.

Comment: I didn't give it the downvote but as you say it is not an entire answer. Maybe try posting something that is an entire answer. I did it myself with a group by clause and max() on all the other values.